# Asynchronous Route Constraints in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have some custom route constraints that validates route tokens.

```
[Route("{locale:locale}", Name = "HomeLocale")]
```

The locale Value (us) for example has to be validated to ensure is allowed value.
The list of allowed values is retrieved from API with HTTP call.

Example code below:

```
internal sealed class LocaleRouteTokenConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{                
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.UrlGeneration) //Always match when generating Urls
            return true;

        var routeTokenValue = values[routeKey].ToString();            

        //TODO Call API and check values

        return true;
    }       
}
```

What would be the best apporach to do this?
I am wondering as `IRouteConstraint` does not provide `async` method and I would have to wait for task completion (with `.Result` or `.Wait()`)
Also this obviously will run at every request.

Answer (score 0):

For `Route`, it is used to route the request to the specific controller action.

As you know, there is no async method for `IRouteConstraint`, and you should not use `.Result` or `.Wait()` in `IRouteConstraint` which will cost much performance.

In general, `IRouteConstraint` is used to route the request, you may check the `tokens` in MVC Filter `IActionFilter` after the request routes to the specific method.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it may be the possible solution. The thing I do not like is that I will have to have route validation logic spread in two places - Constraints for tokens syntax validation and Filters for values validation.

Comment: @AleksanderBethke If you must, you may consider cache all the available values from `api`, and then check the `tokens` from cache instead of sending requests from `IRouteConstraint `.

Comment: Yep obvioulsy all those calls will be cached but it still feels not right. There must be some reason why they have not implemented Async version of Match inside IRouteConstraint :)